# Additional POST data for django

Tags: django, forms, post

I'm using Django and I am having trouble passing variable information back to the server without modifying the url.  Here's what I have which works the way I want except that I want the action to be /foo:

```
<form method="post" action="/foo/{{ variable }}">
  <input type="submit" value="bar"/>
</form>
```

When I do this I can easily get the variable when I parse the url.  Instead, I want to add the variable to the POST QueryDict.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. just add additional input fields:

```
<form method="post" action="/foo/">
  <input type="hidden" value="{{ variable }}" name="name_of_var">
  <input type="submit" value="bar"/>
</form>
```

Then you can access the variable in the view by:

```
request.POST['name_of_var']
```

or if you are not sure if the variable exists. This will not raise exception is does not exist.

```
request.POST.get('name_of_var')
```

Comment: There is no name of an input.

Comment: What's the difference between request.POST.name_of_var and request.POST['name_of_var']?

Comment: request.POST['name_of_var'] works. The version given by miki725 doesn't.

Comment: by bad. I guess I am tired. not thinking straight. `request.POST` is a `MultiDict` and should be accessed using item lookup notation.

Answer (score 3):

Just make an input inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ variable }}" name="foo" />
```

Then on a view:

```
foo = request.POST.get('foo', None)
```

Also, I recomend you to use [url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url) for `action`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a hidden input element with the name and value you need like so:

```
<input type="hidden" name="varname" value="myvalue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not make the variable an input field in the form? You can make it hidden to avoid overriding it. This will post the data in the submit and achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this what the Django sessions framework is for?  You can pass data back and forth without trying to pass it through a url.

> The session framework lets you store and retrieve arbitrary data on a per-site-visitor basis. It stores data on the server side and abstracts the sending and receiving of cookies.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/http/sessions/

Comment: NM this is not what the OP wanted to do.